# How to get data from another table using sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 MySQL tables which are below :

**users** table (`st_id` is station table primary key)

```
uid  fname  lname company_name  email    phone  st_id
=====================================================
9    xxx    yyyy  zzzz          x@y.com  xxx    5,6
```

**station** table

```
st_id  uid   st_name  st_lat  st_long  lg_id
============================================
5      9     xxx      24.25   24.95    8,9,10
6      9     yyy      23.25   23.95    11,12,12
```

Now using **one** SQL query I want to get all data from `users` table and all `st_name` from `station` table which `st_id` is match with `uid`

That's mean it's should return all data from `users` table and all `st_name` from `station` table which `uid` = 9

**My current SQL query :**

```
$getData = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT users.uid, users.company_name, users.fname, users.lname, users.phone, users.email, station.st_id, station.st_name, logger.lg_name FROM users 
LEFT JOIN station ON station.st_id = users.st_id 
LEFT JOIN logger ON logger.lg_id = station.lg_id 
LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id  
WHERE users.power != 'admin' ");
```

**Note:** In `station` table I stored `st_id` values as array. Like :

```
$st_id_value =  implode(',', $st_id_value);
```

**Update Code :**

```
 $getData = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT users.uid, users.company_name, users.fname, users.lname, users.phone, users.email, station.st_id, station.st_name, logger.lg_name 
FROM users LEFT JOIN station
ON FIND_IN_SET(station.st_id, users.st_id)
LEFT JOIN logger ON logger.lg_id = station.lg_id 
LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id
WHERE users.power != 'admin' AND station.uid=$uid");

$fetchData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getData) ;

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($fetchData);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Return :**

```
Array
(
    [uid] => 9
    [company_name] => Source and Services
    [fname] => azad
    [lname] => ahmed
    [phone] => 01671133639
    [email] => azad@gmail.com
    [st_id] => 5
    [st_name] => Rajshahi
    [lg_name] => D4L08841
)
```

Comment: It's not recommended to store multiple values in a single field, better to use a link-table, where each row has a reference to a station and a st_id.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thanks @PugganSe for that advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT users.uid, users.company_name, users.fname, users.lname, users.phone, users.email, station.st_id, station.st_name, logger.lg_name 
FROM users INNER JOIN station
ON FIND_IN_SET(station.st_id, users.st_id)
LEFT JOIN logger ON logger.lg_id = station.lg_id 
LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id
WHERE users.power != 'admin' AND users.uid=9
```

Here you can replace 9 with `uid` you want.

**Update**

```
$getData = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT users.uid, users.company_name, users.fname, users.lname, users.phone, users.email, station.st_id, station.st_name, logger.lg_name 
FROM users LEFT JOIN station
ON FIND_IN_SET(station.st_id, users.st_id)
LEFT JOIN logger ON logger.lg_id = station.lg_id 
LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id
WHERE users.power != 'admin' AND station.uid=$uid");

while($fetchData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getData))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($fetchData);
    echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

Comment: Sure, and I have another question to you that is. Is that database design is right for this purpose ? what do you think ?

Comment: Generally, it is not advised to design in this way. If you have small chunk of data, it is not a big thing. But for large database, it is not good to store multiple values in a single field

Comment: I need to store tons of data :(